# deploying of a contract with Brownie: slowness and errors

Tags: solidity, brownie, infura

I'm currently trying to run deploy a contract on the Sepolia testnet and when I run in the terminal the following line of code

```
brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network sepolia
```

after some minute I get the following error:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 28, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_simple_storage
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 510, in deploy
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 720, in _make_transaction
    gas_price, gas_strategy, gas_iter = self._gas_price(gas_price)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 456, in _gas_price
    return web3.eth.generate_gas_price(), None, None
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 986, in generate_gas_price
    return self._generate_gas_price(transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 214, in _generate_gas_price
    return self.gasPriceStrategy(self.web3, transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\gas_strategies\rpc.py", line 20, in rpc_gas_price_strategy
    return web3.manager.request_blocking(RPC.eth_gasPrice, [])
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 553, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rpc.sepolia.dev', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D41C94EAD0>, 'Connection to rpc.sepolia.dev timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))
```

has anyone already had the same issue?

I already tried other testnet but in vain. The contract is correctly deployed using Ganache.

Answer (score 0):

I Was Facing The Same Problem I Have Just Solved It.
You Just Have To Change The Host Address in Brownie Network Config
Maybe this host='rpc.sepolia.dev' is busy or down

You Can Find Other Host Lists From The https://sepolia.dev/ There Many Host Address. In my case this host  https://rpc-sepolia.rockx.com/ worked..

Comment: Thanks. However I moved to Foundry as Brownie is no more actively mantained.